# In django how to restrict registered user from login

Tags: django, authentication

I have implemented user login in django. I need that when a user registers, that particular user object appears in my users table of auth in admin page but that same user cannot login until he verifies himself by clicking on a url.

For this aim to accomplish I require that by default a user cannot login when he registers on the site. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the registration form, set is_active to False, create a function which emails a token  link to the user which he uses to activate himself.
Most of this is already available in django-userena:
https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena

Comment: Ideally this should work, but even when i put user.is_active = False in def save() function of form  :                                              user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False),
user.is_active = False,
    if commit:,
        user.save(),                           in forms.py and register a user ,,he is able to login after registering, even through admin page if I uncheck active of a user ,, he is able to login,,,,,                                                                                        please guide me,, where I am mistaken,, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a decorator?
`The login_required decorator does NOT check the is_active flag on a user.`